# How can I create collapsing toolbar in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

[image]

I need to create a page like above.
An image is placed on the top of two division..
Or in-between toolbar and content I want to place a image like above picture.
I didn't find any documentation on this in ionic forum.
If any one have created page like this in ionic 3 please share your code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by following this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/) with some modifications

First, generate a component, in your terminal

```
ionic g component expandable-header
```

Then you import it in your `app.module`

Edit your `expandable-header.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'expandable-header',
    templateUrl: 'expandable-header.html'
})

export class ExpandableHeaderComponent {

    @Input('scrollArea') scrollArea: any;
    @Input('headerHeight') headerHeight: number;
    newHeaderHeight: any;

    constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'height', this.headerHeight + 'px');

        this.scrollArea.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => {
      this.resizeHeader(ev);
        });
    }

    resizeHeader(ev){

        ev.domWrite(() => {

            this.newHeaderHeight = this.headerHeight - ev.scrollTop;

            if(this.newHeaderHeight < 0){
                this.newHeaderHeight = 0;
            }  

            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'height', this.newHeaderHeight + 'px');

            for(let headerElement of this.element.nativeElement.children){

            let totalHeight = headerElement.offsetTop + headerElement.clientHeight;

            if(totalHeight > this.newHeaderHeight && !headerElement.isHidden){
                headerElement.isHidden = true;
            } else if (totalHeight <= this.newHeaderHeight && headerElement.isHidden) {
                headerElement.isHidden = false;
            }
        }

     });

   }
}
```

Edit your `expandable-header.html`

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Edit your `expandable-header.scss`

```
expandable-header {
    display: block;
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

In the page where you want to do this, in `html`

```
<ion-header>
    <expandable-header [scrollArea]="myContent" headerHeight="150">
        <img src="https://avatars.io/instagram/pathmoretravelled" />
        <!-- sample image -->
    </expandable-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen #myContent>
    <!-- your code here --> 
</ion-content>
```

in `.scss`

```
expandable-header {
    background-color: #363636;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;

    img {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 75px;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this dependency [ion-collapse-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-collapse-header)